# Why doesn't this show the hidden files/folders?

Tags: disk-usage

I was looking through my system with `du -sch ./*` to find the big useless files I may have stockpiled with no reason, when I found this:

```
$ du -sch ./*
du: cannot read directory ‘./drbunsen/.gvfs’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘./drbunsen/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
18G ./drbunsen
18G total

$ cd drbunsen/
$ du -sch ./*
601M ./Desktop
20K ./Documents
598M ./Downloads
4.0K ./flash
4.0K ./Music
8.0M ./Pictures
4.0K ./Public
4.0K ./Templates
4.0K ./Ubuntu One
8.0K ./Videos
11G ./VirtualBox VMs
6.9M ./workspace
12G total
```

How do I make hidden files visible? `du -sch ./.*` gives the same result as `du -sch ./*`.

Comment: [`du -hs .[^.]* *`](http://superuser.com/questions/342448/du-command-does-not-parse-hidden-directories/633808#633808) for all hidden files, ***excluding*** `.` and `..` which other answers seem to be missing.

Comment: Not enough rep here to answer this highly active question, so a quick comment instead. If under bash, you can "fix" this by using the `dotglob` shell option. I use a subshell here so that it does not affect globally for other commands => `(shopt -s dotglob; du -shc *)`

Comment: What does the 2nd `*` do?

Comment: Thanks, @Zeitounator. I also learned that the `()` start a subshell.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Use

```
du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h
```

in your home folder.

Alternatively, the command I use most frequently is

```
ncdu
```

Easy to install if needed:

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius.
I am not a master in bash, what doe [!.] do?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen: It's a glob that lists all the files that start with a single `.`. Here's a neat trick: if you don't know what a glob-looking thing does, try running `echo .[!.]*` or whatever. The shell will then expand the glob and pass it into `echo`, printing out the list of files that results.

Comment: That fails to list files named like  `..foo` and may cause problems  with files whose name starts with `-`. It could also fail if the arg list is too long. `du -ahd1` would have none of those problems.

Comment: Irrelevant to the original question, but relevant to day to day usage:
It might be useful to include 'c'  switch to display the total and to reorder the options a bit to make this command a little bit easier to remember: `du -cksh .[!.]* * |sort -h`.

Comment: Nice glob. But this does only work if you actually have hidden files on the top level. Hidden files inside directories will still not be counted.And thnak you for `ncdu`.

Answer (score 78):

I have same question in coreutils mailing list, because it was hard to me to remember this weird command by @don.joey. And Bob Proulx [proposed](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2015-06/msg00063.html) better, more natural command: 
`du -ahd1 | sort -h`

> If you want to list all of the files in the current directory then
>   either use '.' or don't give it any file arguments at all.  Also you
>   may want to use the -d, --max-depth=N option.
>
> Try this:
>
> du -hd1

Comment: Add the `-a` option for it to be equivalent.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it's simpler and easier to remember and understand.

Answer (score 10):

When you run that same command inside the directory, it is not including the hidden files which start with `.` in the count. If you have Steam for example installed, it default to installing games under `~/.local/share/Steam/` and it itself is installed there as well.

Under bash you apparently need to run `du -sch .[!.]* *` as it does not properly expand the `.*` glob. Under `zsh` or other shells, `du -sch * .*` should work, as `.*` should be expanded to include the list of all hidden files in the current directory.

Comment: OK. There is apparently a problem with bash then, as it doesn't seem to properly expand `.*`. But `du -sch * .*` does do the correct thing under `zsh`. Under bash, `du -sch .*` seems to count `.` but doesn't expand to show files individually.

Comment: For me .* also expands to ../* and therefore du goes out of the directory that I want to see its size! I had to use ./.[^.]* instead.

Comment: It's zsh and all the shells derived from the Forsyth shell (nowadays that's mostly only pdksh and its derivatives) that do the right thing and don't expand . and .. here. All the other Bourne-like shells do (bash, Bourne, AT&T ksh, dash, yash...).  In `zsh`, you'd use `du -sch -- *(D)` though, not `du -sch -- * .*`.

Answer (score 3):

This also works to show hidden files and dirs:

```
du -sch $(ls -A .) | sort -h
```

Comment: This command doesn't work for files or directories that contain a space character in their names.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `du` utility has a command line switch to process hidden files by default.

One way of achieving this is to use the `find` utility to find the hidden files that you are interested in and then run the `du` utility on each entry:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -exec  du -hs {} \;
```

This gives you additional flexibility as you may only be interested in directories:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -exec  du -hs {} \;
```

Or you may want to see all hidden files and directories deep to the current working directory:

```
find ./ -name '.*' -exec  du -hs {} \;
```

It's not much harder to sort the output, so you can easily identify large hidden files that could help you save disk space:

```
{ find ./ -maxdepth 1 -iname '.*' -exec  du -hs \{\} \; ;} | sort -h
```