# Disk full, but no big file on Ubuntu sever

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

I'm running Ubuntu on nVirtual Box. This vm has 2 disk mounted. One for the OS and for the media files. The media disk is mounted as `sdb1`. When I check for disk space using `df -h`, I'm getting 100% full on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root, the OS drive. The output is below

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.2G  8.7M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root   58G   55G   27M 100% /
tmpfs                        5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    720M  109M  575M  16% /boot
/dev/sdb1                   1008G   13G  945G   2% /media/MT
tmpfs                        1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

So I ran `sudo du -d1 -h /`, and it's reporting 79G of usage, with 75GB coming from the media disk (sdb1) mount. the output is as follow

```
584M    /var
4.0K    /srv
16M     /bin
16K     /lost+found
24K     /tmp
714M    /lib
13M     /sbin
4.0K    /mnt
75G     /media
1.4G    /usr
8.0K    /snap
8.7M    /run
du: cannot access '/proc/5965/task/5965/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5965/task/5965/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5965/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/5965/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       /proc
6.4M    /etc
32K     /root
484M    /home
1.1G    /opt
4.0K    /lib64
0       /dev
0       /sys
108M    /boot
79G     /
```

So, practically, I am only  using 4GB of space in the OS drive, but why is it reporting full?

I have tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I cleaned up /var/log to only about 17M remaining. I also followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413358/disk-is-full-but-cannot-find-big-files-or-folders) with no luck. What am I missing??

Comment: Have you tried to reboot ? If you have deleted a large file that is still open by a program data will not be delete from the disk before the program closes.

Answer (score 0):

From your `df` output, it looks like the `/media` directory is part of your root filesystem. Only `/media/MT` subdirectory is on another filesystem (`/dev/sdb1`), not the whole `/media`. `/media/MT` subdirectory takes 13G according to your `df` output, and the whole `/media` directory 75G according to your `du` output. So there must be 75-13=62G in `/media` directory outside of your `sdb1` disk (outside of `/media/MT` subdirectory), ie. on the root filesystem. It's strange why `df` is reporting only 55G used on the root filesystem, but it is possible that `du` and `df` are counting differently. Anyway, try to move everything that's in your `/media` directory, but not in `/media/MT` subdirectory to that subdirectory. That should free up space on the root filesystem.