# My server's disk space is full but I can't see where it comes from

Tags: server, disk, disk-usage

today my server crashed and I realized that it was because there was no more space available on my disk

When I enter `df -H` I've got this :

```
udev            997M     0  997M   0% /dev
tmpfs           203M  1.1M  202M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        21G   21G   76M 100% /
```

So the files that takes a lot of space is in /

but when I type `ls -a -Ssl --block-size=k /` I've got this :

```
16K drwx------   2 root root 16K Sep 30 21:59 lost+found
 4K drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4K Feb 17 15:01 .
 4K drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4K Feb 17 15:01 ..
 4K drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4K Feb  9 06:52 boot
 4K drwxr-xr-x 102 root root  4K Feb 10 06:19 etc
 4K drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4K Nov 14 18:12 home
 4K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4K Sep 30 21:43 media
 4K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4K Sep 30 21:43 mnt
 4K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4K Sep 30 21:43 opt
 4K drwx------   7 root root  4K Feb 17 15:04 root
 4K drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4K Nov 14 19:19 snap
 4K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4K Sep 30 21:43 srv
 4K drwxrwxrwt  12 root root  4K Feb 17 15:09 tmp
 4K drwxr-xr-x  15 root root  4K Sep 30 21:50 usr
 4K drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4K Feb 17 15:00 var
 0K drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4K Feb 17 15:01 dev
 0K drwxr-xr-x  30 root root  1K Feb 17 15:08 run
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 libx32 -> usr/libx32
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 lib32 -> usr/lib32
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 lib64 -> usr/lib64
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 sbin -> usr/sbin
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 bin -> usr/bin
 0K lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  1K Sep 30 21:43 lib -> usr/lib
 0K dr-xr-xr-x 171 root root  0K Feb 17 15:00 proc
 0K dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root  0K Feb 17 15:00 sys
```

So It's like empty... I really don't understand from where these 21go comes from

Any ideas ?

Thank you and I wish you a great day :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disk is full, but cannot find big files or folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413358/disk-is-full-but-cannot-find-big-files-or-folders)

Comment: You do not say what version of Ubuntu this is  If sda1 is when the OS is installed it is less then the min recommended for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

ls doesn't calculate size of folder contents

you can use [du](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/du.1.html) to calculate folder content sizes

e.g `sudo du / -d 1 -h -c`

starting at root "/" one directory level "-d 1" human readable "-h" give total "-c"

can then  repeat for large folders

you may get some "cannot access" for various reasons